# "solving iteratively"

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is "solving iteratively" something one can do by hand during an exam? For instance, how could I perform the following two calculations by hand?

> We have from the initial conditions
>
> $$x_0 = A + \left(\frac{3}{32} \frac{\kappa}{m} A^2 \omega_0^2 \right) A$$
> which is solved iteratively
>
> $$A \simeq x_0 - \left(\frac{3}{32} \frac{\kappa}{m} x_0^2 \omega_0^2\right) x_0$$
> leading to a final result…

> … as our approximate solution. The amplitude $A$ should be adjusted to match the initial condition. In this case we have $q(0) = 1$, leading to
> $$1 = A - \frac{A^2}{2}c + \frac{A^2}{6} c+\frac{A^3 c^2}{48} + O(c^3)$$
> This may be solved iteratively for $A$
> $$A(c) = 1+\frac{1}{3}c+\frac{29}{144}c^2+\dots$$

Problem is one regarding [secular perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Lindstedt_method) in physics:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the question please? It's hard to infer what's happening from parts of the solution only!

Comment: @sal editted to include the problem (physics)